# Unable to update the buttons in qt dialogue box

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to change the language of the qt dialogue box along with 2 buttons "OK" and "CLOSE", but i'm unable to do so, i'm just able to change the language of text message.

PFB code :

```
void updateDiagWidgets() {
QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(MY_String);
QString qyes = QString::fromStdString(MY_String_YES);
QString qno = QString::fromStdString(MY_String_NO);
if(gDiagBox != NULL) {

    gDiagBox->setText(qstr);
    replaint();
    QPushButton* yesBtn = gDiagBox->addButton(qyes, QMessageBox::YesRole);
    gDiagBox->addButton(qno, QMessageBox::NoRole);
    gDiagBox->setDefaultButton(yesBtn);
}
else {
 QMessageBox *msgBox = new QMessageBox(browser);
 if(msgBox != NULL) {
    DEBUG("updateDiagWidgets Message string is %s\n",MY_String.c_str());
    DEBUG("updateDiagWidgets YES string is %s\n",MY_String_YES.c_str());
    DEBUG("updateDiagWidgets NO string is %s\n",MY_String_NO.c_str());

    msgBox->setWindowTitle("");
    msgBox->setText(qstr);
    msgBox->setParent(0);
    msgBox->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
    msgBox->setWindowFlags(Qt::BypassWindowManagerHint);
    QPushButton* yesBtn = msgBox->addButton(qyes, QMessageBox::YesRole);
    msgBox->addButton(qno, QMessageBox::NoRole);
    msgBox->setDefaultButton(yesBtn);
    gDiagBox = msgBox;
    DEBUG("updateDiagWidgets done msgBox updation");
 }
 else {
    DEBUG("updateDiagWidgets Error allocating memory for dialog box");
 }
}
}
```

I'm able to change the language of qstr alone in the above code, but i'm unable to change the language of qyes and qno.
Kindly help me out with this.

Thanks IN Advance.

Comment: You can share your entire project via github, drive or similar, since your example is incomplete, for example do not indicate if you want to change the text when the widget has been shown.

Comment: I want to the translated string of YES and NO to appear on the qt msg box button when the language is changed.
please know that we already have a function to change the language and i have the changed string, i just want to update that changed string dynamically after language has been changed.

Comment: What language? Nowhere is that seen in the code, so I ask you to share the complete code since if the code shown is not complete.

Comment: You are doing something strange here. You are adding a new set of buttons even though your message box already has buttons in it. Use [`QMessageBox::button`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#button) to get an existing button from the message box, and set a new text to it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use tr() in your App ? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html